# Как генерировать большие числа типа long в c#?

Tags: c#

Мне для шифрования нужно генерировать большие числа типа long, можно ли в c# сгенерировать число заданной длинной битов? Нужен именно тип данных long, а не BigInt.

Comment: что значит "генерировать"?

Comment: Случайные числа нужны или что?

Comment: Да, случайное большое число типа long, желательно генерация с заданной длиной битов

Comment: Тут рецепты почитайте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651554/random-number-in-long-range-is-this-the-way

Comment: [Random.NextInt64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.nextint64?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Если нужна криптостойкость: [RandomNumberGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Ради развлечения, есть [такой пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1414722/373567), но он не криптостойкий.