# Генератор не случайных чисел

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

В C# есть известный класс Random и метод Next. Если каждый раз объявлять Random с одинаковым сидом, то и Next в соответствующие вызовы будет всегда одинаковым. Я моем случае мне нужно по сиду и параметрам получать случайное число. Является ли приведенный выше метод нормально работающим, или есть какие нибудь другие способы. Я например думал о хэше сид + параметры. Является ли вариант с хэшом лучшим по сравнению с Random?

Comment: Какая-то странная задача. Если вы хотите рандом, то зачем вам сид?

Comment: @AlexeyTen да, задача специфическая. Ну в данном случае есть у нас массив данных, вроде бы случайный, и он очень большой. Изначально он не заполнен и считать все элементы до нужного рандомом не целесообразно. Нужен способ чтобы его можно было заполнять по мере использования.  То есть обратились к 100 000 ячейке, мы знаем что при сиде именно в 100 000 ячейке будут конкретные данные, которые будут случайны исходя из сида и адреса ячейки

Comment: Похоже на проблему XY. Похоже вам подойдет просто хэш от номера ячейки с солью.

Comment: `Random` в современном дотнете весьма качественно сидируется автоматически, относитально случайный сид можно получить из `Random.Shared`. Либо просто вызвать `new Random` без аргументов, и он отсидируется из `Random.Shared`. А сам `Random.Shared` для себя использует системную энтропию для сида, её можно считать весьма качественной. Но само собой, это всё не криптостойкие генерации, поэтому ни `Random`, ни его сиды не подходят для шифрования. А так, вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1415504/373567) есть самопальный генератор сида.